# Create Interface All Optional Fields from class

Tags: typescript

I have a constructor that takes as a parameter an object containing properties of the object.

```
class MyObj {
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    constructor(params){
        for(var i in params)
            this[i] = params[i];
    }
}
```

My goal is to have autocompletion when writing something like `new MyObj({a:1})`.
Right now, I need to create a separated interface to have autocompletion

```
interface MyObjOptions {
    a?:number;
    b?:number;
    c?:number;
    d?:number;
}
```

with `constructor(params:MyObjOptions){...}`

Is there a way to do that without having to duplicate all fields in an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that without having to duplicate all fields in an interface?

You can put the object into a `config` property:

```
interface MyObjOptions {
    a?:number;
    b?:number;
    c?:number;
    d?:number;
}

class MyObj { 
    constructor(public options:MyObjOptions) {
    }
}
```

But if you want *defaults* you have to list them in the interface + write them out so **you must write e.g. `a` twice**. No way around it